# Dúvida - Case when dentro de um stuff - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, como faço para colocar um case when exists dentro da consulta abaixo. O resultado atualmente está saindo assim:

Clientes
Drogaria,Soccer,Gelagua

Porém, quero colocar um case when exists caso estiver na condição, vir sim,senao, vem não. Exemplo:

Drogaria - Sim, Soccer - Sim, Gelagua - Não

```
select
(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((STUFF((
   SELECT
      ':::::: ' + CAST(U.USUNOME AS VARCHAR) + '
 ' FROM Usuario U LEFT JOIN FRM_51 F51C ON U.UsuID = F51C.ContaID LEFT JOIN FRM_52 F52P ON F52P.C01 = F51C.C01  LEFT JOIN Tarefa T ON T.TarID = F52P.TarefaID WHERE  F51C.C04 = 3640 AND F51C.C01 = FRM52.C01 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,1)),'1::::: ',''),':::::: ',''),' &# x0D;
','')) as Clientes 

   from
      usuario
```

Comment: A informação deve vir na horizontal mesmo? Não poderia vir na vertical?

    Drogaria SIM
    Soccer SIM ...

Comment: na horizontal mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, eu fiz a query abaixo, veja se isso ajuda (vi que na sua query tinha muitos replaces e esse monte de ":" então preferi montar um exemplo):

```
select '1' [id], 'a' [texto] into #temp union
select '1' [id], 'b' [texto] union
select '1' [id], 'c' [texto] union
select '1' [id], 'd' [texto] 

select distinct stuff((select ', ' + case when [texto] = 'a' then [texto] + ' - Sim'
                                when texto = 'b' then texto + ' - Nao'
                                else texto + ' - talvez'
                                end
        from #temp t
        where t.id = fora.id for xml path('')),1,2,'')
from #temp fora
```

O resultado disso foi:

```
a - Sim, b - Nao, c - talvez, d - talvez
```

Comment: show de bola @cotiovis. Obrigadão